# How to split dictionary into columns when contains None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm converted a nested JSON file to a dataframe and did several operations, and now part of the dataframe looks like this:

| product | shelfId |
| --- | --- |
| `{'product': []}` | aaa |
| `{'product': []}` | bbb |
| `{'product': [{'id': '111', 'quantity': 10}]}` | ccc |
| `{'product': [{'id': '222', 'quantity': 0}]}` | ddd |

Now I want to flatten the product column, and get a df like:

| id | quantity | shelfId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | aaa |
| NaN | NaN | bbb |
| 111 | 10 | ccc |
| 222 | 0 | ddd |

I've tried:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['product'])
```

and then I got a df like this:

| product |
| --- |
| [] |
| [] |
| `[{'id': '111', 'quantity': 10}]` |
| `[{'id': '222', 'quantity': 0}]` |

and then I tried to do normalize again:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['product'])
```

but shows error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I also tried similar things with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['product'].values.tolist())
```

but basically got similar error. I think this is because of the empty list? Is there a way to solve it?

---

Add sample input:

dict1 = {'products': {0: [], 1: [], 2: [{'id': '111', 'quantity': 10}], 3: [{'id': '222', 'quantity': 0}]}, 'shelfId': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'bbb', 2:'ccc', 3:'ddd'}}

dfnew = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

Comment: Does the nesting only go one layer deep (`product` contains only `id` and `quantity`)?

Comment: Yes, product contains only id and quantity.

Comment: Kindly share the source dataframe as code, using ``df.to_dict()``

Comment: Added a sample dict as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the structure of the `product` column is known and is the same for all records, you can extract `id` and `quantity` with `.str`:

```
x = df.pop('products').str[0]
df['id'] = x.str['id']
df['quantity'] = x.str['quantity']

df
```

Output:

```
  shelfId   id  quantity
0     aaa  NaN       NaN
1     bbb  NaN       NaN
2     ccc  111      10.0
3     ddd  222       0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried this, and got AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! Any ideas on it?

Comment: @ErinLiu Your new example has a slightly different structure. I've updated my answer to work with that

Answer (score 1):

If `product` contains only `id`, `quantity` keys:

```
print(
    pd.concat(
        [
            df["shelfId"],
            pd.DataFrame(
                df["product"]
                .apply(lambda x: x["product"][0] if x["product"] else {})
                .tolist()
            ),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
  shelfId   id  quantity
0     aaa  NaN       NaN
1     bbb  NaN       NaN
2     ccc  111      10.0
3     ddd  222       0.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method but got this: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method to flat the 'product' column which will flat the column data whatever his datatype (dict,list):

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a)
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out
```

Example output:

```
>>> sample_object = {'product': [{'id': '111', 'quantity': 10}]}
>>> flat = flatten_json(sample_object)
>>> json_normalize(flat)
    id  quantity
0  111        10
```